# Can the newly discovered mass of the neutrino explain in part, the missing matter

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, neutrinos

This question is related to the recent discovery of the neutrino mass 0.320 ± 0.081 eV/$c^2$.
Could this account for at least some of the Dark Matter/Missing matter of the universe?

Comment: Neutrinos interact via the electroweak interaction (take for the example inverse beta decay, where an antineutrino and a proton become a positron and a neutron), meaning they are not dark in that sense

Comment: Please, please, [do the obvious search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutrino+dark+matter) before leaping to post a question.

Comment: Is this related to http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5870 (AKA http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.051303)? If so "discovered" is a pretty strong word for a speculative phenomenological paper that depends on sticking in some parameters to get the model right. Especially when the authors include a caveat in the abstract.

Comment: yes i did that but this is not a duplicate question give it was answered prior to the recent discovery of the mass of neutrinos right?
"newly discovered" (with respect to the dmckee this is a Nobel winners Kajita and McDonald must have confidence in these masses to win the prize right?)

Comment: If this is about the Nobel prize then the data is not at all "new", so no the alleged duplicate was not answered before the discovery. The Nobel committee generally awards the prize to work that has stood up to considerable subsequent scrutiny, and in this case the work is started the '90s and reported in 1998 for Super-K and 2001 for SNO. And for all that we still don't know what the masses are (though we have beginning to seriously constrain them) just that at least two of them *must* be non-zero (and most people believe that all three are non-zero).